# Problem with StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I'm trying to use the StringFormat in XAML to populate the Header text on a TabItem.  The code I am using is:

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding MyValue, StringFormat='My Value is {0}'}" />
        <EventSetter Event="FrameworkElement.Loaded" Handler="OnTabItemLoaded" />
        <EventSetter Event="FrameworkElement.Unloaded" Handler="OnTabItemUnloaded" />
    </Style>
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The problem is my header is only showing the value of `MyValue` in the Header and not the formatted text.

Comment: you should consider setting the HeaderStringFormat answer as the correct one. It's a 15 second fix rather than a 15 minute one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the Header property is not a string property.

You need to use a headertemplate containing a TextBlock which you can bind the Text property using your stringformat

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}"> 
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
          <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyValue, StringFormat='My Value is {0}'}" /> 
            </DataTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <EventSetter Event="FrameworkElement.Loaded" Handler="OnTabItemLoaded" /> 
        <EventSetter Event="FrameworkElement.Unloaded" Handler="OnTabItemUnloaded" /> 
    </Style> 
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I had to change the `ControlTemplate` to a `DataTemplate`, but that gave me exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I think nowadays you can simply use HeaderStringFormat, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use the `HeaderStringFormat` property:

```
<Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding MyValue}" />
<Setter Property="HeaderStringFormat" Value="My Value is {0}" />
```

WPF seems to follow this pattern whenever you can assign a string to a generic content property, another example would be [ContentControl.ContentStringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat?view=netframework-4.8).